# What's the benefit of specifying a branch for a submodule?

Tags: git, submodule

Reading the documentation of the git `submodule` command I found out that you can specify a branch for a submodule using

```
git submodule set-branch -branch <branch name> -- <submodule path>
```

This results in a config entry in the `.gitmodules` file

```
> git config --file .gitmodules --get-regex branch
...
submodule.<submodule name>.branch = <branch name>
```

However the documentation did not describe what this data is used for. Submodules are still checked out in the detached head state an I've failed to find a way to use this info to do a checkout for the submodule from the parent repository that sets up the submodule in a state that tracks a branch without doing a checkout inside the submodule directly.

What's the benefit of providing this info (other than the `.gitmodules` file containing info that could be retrieved and used by my own script)? (Or did I simply do the initialisation/update of the submodules the wrong way?)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you add the submodule with --branch option you can use --remote option to update your submodule to the latest commit of that branch.

```
git submodule add -b example URLHERE 
git submodule init
git submodule update --recursive --remote
```

Comment: If there is no branch given for a submodule, then `git submodule update --recursive --remote` will update the submodule the the remote branch that HEAD points to, which is usually master.

Comment: This is my example: `cd SomePathInYourRepo/`
Add submodule `git submodule add -b master https://github.com/buildroot/buildroot` or 
`git submodule add --branch master https://github.com/buildroot/buildroot`

Answer (score 1):

One would use git submodules in order to maintain strict version management over
your external dependencies.

Git submodules allow you to keep, as a subdirectory of your repository, another
repository at a particular snapshot in time,
in this way incorporating and tracking version history of the external code.

A git submodule points to a specific commit in an external repository.
It is static and only tracks specific commits, but it does not
track git refs or branches and is not automatically updated
when that repository is updated. This is the very reason why one
would use branches.

Comment: *A git submodule points to a specific commit in an external repository.* I see no hash in `.gitmodule` file. That means Git submodules point to random position for different people.

Comment: @gavenkoa: The repository commit contains a tree object that has reference to the specific submodule commit to use for that repository commit, whereby the submodule commit to use is specified, thus not random.

Comment: @MortenZilmer You're right. Later I saw `git diff` for submodules containing revisions. Unlike Mercurial Git hides referencing hashes in some binary store.